# How do I list all the paths and directories in my Firebase Storage with Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

I'm using Flutter and in my Firebase Storage I have a complex architecture of files and directories. I would like to list all the files contained in Firebase Storage (including their path) in order to download them and stock them on the local storage of the device.

I know how to list all the files from a folder, but how do I list the files from all the folders at the same time without knowing the name of these folders?

For instance, my architecture could look like this:

```
MainFolder
  -- Folder2
    -- Folder3
      -- file.json
    -- Folder4
      -- file2.json
AnotherMainFolder
  -- file3.json
```

The structure in my Firebase Storage is dynamic (I do not know the name and the number of directories I have inside it).

Until now, I have managed to writke the following code:

```dart
class DownloadFirebaseApi {
  static Future<List<FirebaseFile>> listAll() async {
    // here, I should specify a path `ref(path)`
    // however I don't want to because
    // I want all the folders and all the files
    // no matter in which directory they are
    final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();
    final result = await ref.listAll();
    final urls = await _getDownloadLinks(result.items);
    return urls
        .asMap()
        .map((index, url) {
          final ref = result.items[index];
          final name = ref.name;
          final file = FirebaseFile(name: name, url: url, ref: ref);
          return MapEntry(index, file);
        })
        .values
        .toList();
  }

  static Future<List<String>> _getDownloadLinks(List<Reference> refs) async {
    return Future.wait(refs.map((ref) {
      var url = ref.getDownloadURL();
      return ref.getDownloadURL();
    }).toList());
  }
}
```

Is there a recursive method that I don't know for `listAll()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `listAll` the result has two lists:

1. `result.items`, which contains all individual files in the root.
2. `result.prefixes`, which contains all directories (commonly referred to as "prefixes" in Cloud Storage).

You'll want to loop over `result.prefixes` too, and call `listAll` on each of those in turn to get the full, recursive list of files.

Also see the FlutterFire documentation on [listing files and directories](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/storage/usage#listing-files--directories).

Answer (score 1):

For those who would be interested in knowing how I managed to code that (thanks to the answer of Frank van Puffelen)

```dart
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';

class FirebaseFile {
  final Reference ref;
  final String url;
  final String name;

  FirebaseFile({
    required this.ref,
    required this.url,
    required this.name,
  });

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'file "$name"';
  }
}

class DownloadFirebaseApi {
  /// Transform the items (the files) contained in the [result] (a folder).
  /// The items are transformed into a list of [FirebaseFile] objects.
  static Future<List<FirebaseFile>> _getFilesFrom(ListResult result) async {
    List<String> urls = await _getDownloadLinks(result.items);
    return urls
        .asMap()
        .map((index, url) {
          final ref = result.items[index];
          final name = ref.name;
          final file = FirebaseFile(name: name, url: url, ref: ref);
          return MapEntry(index, file);
        })
        .values
        .toList();
  }

  /// Explores all the nested directories and
  /// returns a list of all the files as [FirebaseFile] objects.
  static Future<List<FirebaseFile>> _exploreDirectories(
    ListResult result,
  ) async {
    List<FirebaseFile> files = [];
    if (result.prefixes.isEmpty) {
      if (result.items.isEmpty) {
        return [];
      } else {
        return await _getFilesFrom(result);
      }
    } else {
      for (Reference prefix in result.prefixes) {
        ListResult nestedResult = await prefix.listAll();
        if (nestedResult.items.isNotEmpty) {
          files.addAll(await _getFilesFrom(nestedResult));
        }
        if (nestedResult.prefixes.isNotEmpty) {
          files.addAll(await _exploreDirectories(nestedResult));
        }
      }
    }
    return files;
  }

  /// Returns a list of all the files as [FirebaseFile] objects.
  static Future<List<FirebaseFile>> listAll() async {
    final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();
    List<FirebaseFile> files = [];
    ListResult result = await ref.listAll();
    if (result.prefixes.isNotEmpty) {
      files = await _exploreDirectories(result);
    } else if (result.items.isNotEmpty) {
      files = await _getFilesFrom(result);
    } else {
      return [];
    }

    return files;
  }

  /// Gets the download URL of every file with their [refs].
  static Future<List<String>> _getDownloadLinks(List<Reference> refs) async {
    return Future.wait(refs.map((ref) => ref.getDownloadURL()).toList());
  }
}
```